# select_tag and upto - whats wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have simple select tag, in which I would like to see numbers from 6 upto 40 and All.
But ruby on rails 3 renders this as selection only with All entry.
I looked in source code, but I dont see anywhere that numbers are rendered. Also, when in console, I got exactly what i was expected

```
select_tag :agey, (6.upto(40){|i| print ("<option>"+i.to_s+"</option>").html_safe }), {:prompt => "All"}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Takes an array

```
<%=  select_tag :agey, options_for_select(6.upto(40)) %>
```

Comment: ay...thank you...when you are tired, you dont think straight :)